# Is it possible to use a CancellationToken with ExecuteReader?

Tags: c#, .net

The new async `ExecuteReaderAsync` takes a CancellationToken. Is there any way to cancel the old synchronous `ExecuteReader`?

In our case, all the data operations are synchronous on a background thread, so `await` is not an option. I don't want to start a second thread- `Task.Run(() => command.ExecuteReaderAsync(token)).Result` seems a waste just to be able to cancel from the UI thread.

Comment: Given you want to stick with synchronous code.. why not just replace `ExecuteReader(...)` with `ExecuteReaderAsync(token, ...).Result` exactly wherever you use the former? You don't have to wrap it with `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Noseratio Duh, I'm used to that causing a deadlock on the UI thread, but in the case of a background thread, `ExecuteReaderAsync(...).Result` works beautifully. Hang on, does it block and use a threadpool thread to handle the continuation action? I think my extension method has the benefit of staying on one thread all the way.

Comment: Yes, `ExecuteReaderAsync(...).Result` will block whatever thread it's called on. But it doesn't necessarily mean it will block *more* threads than that, as it might use async IO behind the scene (I'm not sure about that, but that'd be logical). Anyhow, if you're concerned about your app scalability, use `async/await` and don't block threads redundantly.

Comment: You don't have to use Reflector: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/R/7c74c94bc7beae1d.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance tests showed almost 2x performance benefit to a using a dedicated synchronous data-reading thread, compared to using the Begin or Async APIs with their thread pool continuations. (Since tens of millions of rows will be loaded in as many seconds, we prefer performance in this case.)

An extension method for convenient token passing:

```
public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(this SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior commandBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        using (cancellationToken.Register(command.Cancel))
            return command.ExecuteReader(commandBehavior);
    }
    catch (SqlException) when (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I did some spelunking with Reflector decompilation. The Begin and Async versions are both very frugal, but are both fully based on the TPL async. Because of that, there is thread pool dispatching for continuations on both.

This extension method has no threading overhead. The thread that calls `Cancel` on the token source will also call `command.Cancel` which will immediately cause a `SqlException` in the data thread.

Comment: Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I can't respond authoritatively to your edit but there's a few things you should know about your initial question:

1. `Task.Run( ... ).Result` is blocking; that syntax is a little misleading.
2. `await Task.Run( () => command.ExecuteReaderAsync(token));` will block only the remainder of the executing method; allowing the rest to be treated as a callback.
3. `await Task.Run( () => command.ExecuteReaderAsync(token), token);` works as above but allows the task parallel library to honor to your cancellation token as well.

As to the main question, [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204838%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests that ExecuteReaderAsync() is truly honoring that cancellationToken.  Bear in mind there are a couple of methods in the framework that will not actually do that.

Comment: Yes, `.Result` is blocking just as `ExecuteReader` is. The synchronous `ExecuteReader` is what I would prefer to use. This is all on a background thread with no need for async continuation scheduling, so `await` is out of the question.